# automatic creating CODEOWNER file for multiple git repositories

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, devops, github-codeowners

I'm managing a lot of repositories in BitBucket and want to start using CODEOWNER file for all the repositories. i have a general template for all repositories for CODEOWNER file which i want to add to all the repositories.
is there an easy way to do it instead of adding the same CODEOWNER file to each repository manually?